# How do I access WSL localhost

Tags: fastapi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a simple FastAPI application in WSL2 in a anaconda env, the code is very simple, as in the image

[image: 1]

The app is running in localhost:127.0.0.1:8000 but I can't access it from Windows browser.

How do I do it, because later I want to test the API using swagger ui?

I used `ip route` or `wsl hostname -i` command to see the ip of WSL machine but none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, turned out I still have a VPN running and it seems that it prevented me from accessing